# Is it possible to allow egress traffic by hostname?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

K8s network policies allow specifying CIDRs, but I'd like to specify DNS name.

On a high level I'd see it working the following way:

- There's a whitelist of allowed hosts
- k8s intercepts IP resolution requests and checks whether host is whitelisted
- if yes, resolved IPs are temporarily added to network policy thus allowing for egress traffic

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Which CNI are you using?

Comment: @gohm'c EKS with vpc-cni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vpc-cni does not implement k8s network policies. You need to replace vpc-cni with one of the EKS compatible CNI of your choice [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alternate-cni-plugins.html) that support using FQDN in the policy. Note upgrade may be required (eg. Calico Enterprise) to have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is possible by programmaticaly create the NP object.

You could use argo-workflow, to resolve the hostname then create the NP.

Or much better, develop an operator!